# Strapi HTTPS Nginx Config

Tags: node.js, nginx, strapi

I am trying to set up a node WebApp with Strapi as a CMS, both running on Nginx. Having followed the [strapi documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#strapi-server), I can access the login page but every POST attempt returns a 500 Internal Server error.

[image: Response with error]

On Nginx acces log I've got:

```
"POST /strapi/admin/forgot-password HTTP/1.1" 500 134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0" 
"POST /strapi/admin/login HTTP/1.1" 500 134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0"
```

In the Strapi CLI output I see only GET requests, it seems that Strapi doesn't receive POST requests:

[image: Strapi CLI output]

Anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I had to add the webapp url to the cors settings in /config/middleware.js

[image]